# Best way to prevent "using" from using a specific constructor from a framework class

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4

I've got a wpf application and use the EF4 to communicate with a database.
I'm choosing the connectionstring dynamically, dependent on if a debugger is attach or not:

```
public static string CustomerConnectionString;
public static string ProjectsConnectionString;

private static void GetConnectionstring()
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
         CustomerConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kundenEntities"].ConnectionString;
         ProjectsConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projekteEntities"].ConnectionString;
    }
    else
    {
         CustomerConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kundenEntitiesRelease"].ConnectionString;
         ProjectsConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projekteEntitiesRelease"].ConnectionString;
    }


}
```

I'm doing this, to ensure not to accidently do stuff in the productive database.

An entity object is created on that way then:

```
using (ProjectEntities proj = new ProjectEntities(App.ProjectsConnectionString))
{ 
    I'm proper code
}
```

Now I want to ensure, that I'm not accidently calling the default constructor to get the entity object.
That would cause that the entity object would use the default connectionstring from the app.config. The default connectionstring is the debug one, which connects to my local database.
Should be clear, that if that happens, the data that is getting queried from that entity
is working in my debugger, but wouldn't work for the user, because that user hasn't got an connection to my local database (-:

I did a workaround for now and derived the entity class and provide just the constructor that requires the connectionstring:

```
public class ProjectEntities : projekteEntities
{
    public ProjectEntities(string connectionString) : base  (connectionString){}
}
```

**Update**

I solve dit to my needs on that way:

I renamed the generted projekteEntitites class...

```
public partial class ObsoleteProjekteEntities : ObjectContext
{
    #region Konstruktoren

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialisiert ein neues projekteEntities-Objekt mithilfe der in Abschnitt 'projekteEntities' der Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei gefundenen Verbindungszeichenfolge.
    /// </summary>
    public ObsoleteProjekteEntities() : base("name=projekteEntities", "projekteEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialisiert ein neues projekteEntities-Objekt.
    /// </summary>
    public ObsoleteProjekteEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "projekteEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialisiert ein neues projekteEntities-Objekt.
    /// </summary>
    public ObsoleteProjekteEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "projekteEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

and derived that class...

```
public class ProjectEntities : ObsoleteProjekteEntities
{
    public ProjectEntities(string connectionString) : base  (connectionString){}
}
```

...now I won't accidently call the original generated context with the default constructor.

Thanks for the other suggestions, will have a look at them too (-:

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: The default parameterless constructor is not callable if there is another one with parameters. (Reflection asides, not sure about that)

Comment: So you mean that `projekteEntities` is a generated context class with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: The only way to stop code being callable is to not write it.  A constructor in a `using` statement is no different to anywhere else.  Why not just have a single entry in the config file but modify the config file between local and release environments?  I mean, that *is* what a configuration file is generally used for...

Comment: yeah, 'projekteEntities' is a generated conext class. And I want prevent that I accidently call that constructor. Well I 'solved' it to my needs on that way now, that I renamed 'projekteEntities' to 'ObsoleteProjekteEntities', derived that class: ProjectsEntities : ObsoleteProjekteEntities..which just provides the constructor taht takes the one with the connectionstring.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already managing both release and debug connection string in your code, then comment out connection string in the web.config file. Even better, use .config file transformation tool to do this. [Take a look at this tutorial.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx)

Secondly, don't rely on coders to take care which connection string is used each time. Don't use `Debugger.IsAttached` to decide between debug and release mode. If someone runs the application without debugger, it will hit release database. Instead use C# pre-processor directives.

For example:

- Go to Project properties
- Go to `Build` tab
- Check `Define DEBUG constant`
- Go to file where you're setting the connection string and use following code:

---

```
#if DEBUG
CustomerConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kundenEntities"].ConnectionString;
ProjectsConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projekteEntities"].ConnectionString;
#else
CustomerConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kundenEntitiesRelease"].ConnectionString;
ProjectsConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projekteEntitiesRelease"].ConnectionString;
#endif
```

---

Comment: Preprocessor directives are still useless: I can run a Release-mode build from Visual Studio, and I could release a Debug-mode build to a live server.  Compilation options shouldn't configure the software!

Comment: If you want to screw up your database no one can stop you, but pre-processor directives are still better protection than checking if there is a debugger attached. And we're not talking about actually producing software configuration, but altering between configurations.

Comment: I'd assume the OP has no such thing, but if I were running integration tests on a build server, I'd expect that to be running a release build that should have a different configuration to the production build.  Altering between configurations is why a configuration file exists!  Why not actually use it that way?  (Your suggestion on config transforms is a *good* answer, but preprocessor directives for this stuff is horrendous.)